# Can't import views from application the the URLS of project in Django 3.1

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I'm not able to import my views in the app folder to the URLS of project folder. I've tried every possible methods like 'from . import views' or 'from newapp import views as newapp_views' and 2-3 more alternatives that I searched on the internet. My app name is newapp and project name is newproject. Please help me.

```
This is my models file:

from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=128)
    
last_name=models.CharField(max_length=128)
    
email=models.EmailField(max_length=256, unique=True)



This is my URLS of newapp folder:

from django.conf.urls import url

from django.urls.resolvers import URLPattern

from .models import views

urlpatterns= [url(r'^$', views.users, name='users'),
]

This is my views of newapp folder:

from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import User

def index(request):
    
        return render(request, 'newapp/index.html')

def users(request):
    
        user_list=User.objects.order_by('first_name')
    

        user_dict={'users': user_list}
    
        return render(request, 'newapp/users.html', context=user_dict)


This is my URLS of newproect folder:

from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path,include

from newapp import views

     urlpatterns = [
   
          path('', views.index, name='index'),
          path('users/',views.users, name="users"),
          path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]


This is my settings file:


    from pathlib import Path
    
    import os
    
    BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
    
    TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
    
    DEBUG = True
    
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
    
    
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        
        'django.contrib.admin',
    
        'django.contrib.auth',
    
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    
        'django.contrib.sessions',
    
        'django.contrib.messages',
    
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
        'newapp'
    ]
    
    
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    
            'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
    
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error? What do you mean you can't?

Comment: When i'm going with 'from newapp import views', it s showing error: path('', views.index, name='index'),
AttributeError: module 'newapp.views' has no attribute 'index'

Comment: When i'm going with 'from . import views', it s showing error:   from . import views
ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from 'newproject' (C:\Users\acer\Documents\djangoprojects\newproj\newproject\newproject\__init__.py)

Answer (score 0):

You can't import your file like this: `from newapp import views`.

And `from . import views` will work only if your `urls.py` file is in your app folder, while Django by default put it inside your project folder.

If you choose to have separated `urls.py` files per app (which is a good practice, as your project could grow into many apps), you could do the following:

**newapp/urls.py**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('users/',views.users, name="users"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

**newproject/urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('newapp.urls'))
]
```

This way you just include the app urls in the project url file, and you can use a path to prefix all the app urls (instead of a blank string as above).

Comment: But I've already made a different views file for the app folder. I've given the code for both the URLs file above.

Comment: @AsadTayyab I hadn't noticed that, so I edited my answer to give you an example of separated `url.py` files.

Comment: @AsadTayyab No problem! Please consider accepting my answer :)